# How to filter Google Analytics by actual domain name supplied in GA script?

Tags: filter, google-analytics

When using the following snippet in your Google Analytics script

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.domainname.com']);`

How do I filter my views by this value?

A lot of people suggest to filter by 'Hostname' but this value is from the browser not by the DomainName value above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this domain name is available in the UI. This domain name API is used for setting the cookies etc. To do what you want, you should set a custom variable with the value of the domain name that you want.